# Configuring Google Analytics Event to Capture Video.js Decile/Quartile Plays

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, video.js

We are in the process of implementing Video.js (open source video player) on our website and we'd like to track engagement with the videos.  I found a plugin ([videojs-ga](https://github.com/videojs/video.js)) that will send Events to Google Analytics with minimal development effort required.  There are a bunch of events the plugin tracks but the most important event is the `percent played` Event Action, which sends an Event Value of `10`, `20`, etc. based on how far the user has watched the video.  It is configurable, so I could send every 25% if I wanted quartile reporting (common request for publishers/advertisers).

A typical event looks like this: `{eventCategory: "Video", eventAction: "percent played", eventLabel: "example-video-title", eventValue: 40}`.

All of the data is being passed into GA but I can't pull the reports I want due to how the event is configured.  Right now the best I can pull is a list of video titles (Event Label) for the `percent played` Event Action with the following metrics: `Total Events`, `Unique Events`, `Event Value` (sum of all values passed), and `Avg. Value`.  Here's an [example of what I can pull out of GA currently](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ac0ad6322fa7465b55d9).

Here's what I'd like to be able to pull: for a specific time period (e.g. Yesterday) I'd like a list of each video title and the number of events that reached the 10% mark (aka a value of `10` in the `Event Value`), the number of events that reached the 20% mark, etc.  This would allow me to understand and what point in the video do users began to fall off.  Here's an [example of the report I'd like to pull](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/46a26ff0f1ed936c9e79).

I believe I can't pull this type of report currently, correct?  I'm comfortable querying the GA API if that's a viable solution.

Assuming I'm not able to pull the data in a way I'd like, can you recommend how I would go about altering how I configure the `percent play` event?  Should I utilize a Custom Dimension or Custom Metric?

Any advice is much appreciated, thanks!